# Narrowband DOA Beamforming techniques on Wideband signal

Tags: phase, beamforming

I'm trying to implement a tracking system (undergrad thesis) using DOA of acoustic signals. I'm testing this by playing a 2kHz sound and receiving the signal with four microphones in a ULA.

So, the band I'm interested in is narrowband but naturally the signal received is wideband.

I have been able to successfully implement a time delay beamformer however when I have tried to implement a phase shift beamformer I have failed.

My suspicion is that you can only perform phase shift beamforming techniques on narrowband signals and will not work even if you are looking for a narrowband within a wideband signal. Am I correct?

If so, will a simple filter be good enough to correct this issue to transform the signal into a narrowband one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My suspicion is that you can only perform phase shift beamforming techniques on narrowband signals and will not work even if you are looking for a narrowband within a wideband signal. Am I correct?

No; the correlation coefficient of your reference signal to your received signal should, given additive, phase-uniform, white noise, have an expectation value of the phase shift the individual receiver sees, no matter how wide your band is.

Note that this is only true if your transmitter/receiver system can be modeled as linear phase for the bandwidth we're talking about, but without loss of generality, radar/sonar/sound systems are designed to pretty much have exactly that characterestic.

Comment: i'm not using a reference signal, just getting the power of the output...

Comment: well, that's not phase estimation then, is it

Comment: maybe not, fairly new to this, i initially implemented a delay and sum beamformer, which worked using a time delay implementation but stopped working when i tried implementing it with a standard steering vector. i then tried using matlab's phased array object, and it worked for the time delay beamformer but couldnt get it to work with the phase delay beamformer. but i havent seen any mention of a reference signal.

Comment: sorry, I should have clarified that: I meant to say "pick any of your receiver elements, declare it as your reference, correlate against other elements' signals, and you should get complex correlation coefficients that include angle of arrival info"

Comment: I'm a little confused about you implementing it with a steering vector: That vector is what you want to estimate if you do a DOA estimator, isn't it?

Comment: ah yes that is what i'm doing. The literature i've been looking at define the steering vector as a vector that you multiply your matrix of sensor inputs with to steer your microphones to point at a specific angle. Then you run through all angles of interest and look for maximum power output.

Comment: Can you do the following: Take two receiver branch signals; Transform them to Frequency domain (`fft`); divide one by the other; Fourier transform the result and plot abs(result). The frequency you see should be proportional to the time difference of the two signals, even if that is fractional

Comment: do you mean inverse it and plot the result? i did that and got this:
http://imgur.com/a/0XhJz

Comment: if I read your chart correctly, this is only 150 samples; could you take a longer measurment?

Comment: http://imgur.com/a/iHrHk

Comment: Hm; I expected that to be more consistent. To explain: the idea is that we take the "earlier" channel, and say "hey, that's $r_0(t)$", and expect the "later" channel to be $r_1(t) = a r_0(t-\Delta t),\, a\in \mathbb R$ with $\Delta t$ the time difference between these two channels and $a$ an attenuation. Now, in frequency domain, a time shift becomes a modulation, so $R_1(f) = \mathcal F\{r_1(t)\}(f) = a R_0(f) e^{j2\pi f \Delta t}$; now $\frac{R_1}{R_0} = a e^{j2\pi f \Delta t}$, which transforms nicely to $\mathcal F\{\frac{R_1}{R_0}\}=a\mathcal F\{e^{j2\pi \Delta t f}\}=a\delta(t-\Delta t)$

Comment: that's why I was expecting a nicer "peak" somewhere. What kind of audio is your source that you try to locate?

Comment: ah, there wouldn't be any peaks because those pictures are of a signal perpendicular to the the microphones :p http://imgur.com/a/zx6OS

Comment: so this works better with angled signal direction?

Comment: A signal that is perpendicular to the microphones will arrive simultaneously at each one. Dividing 1 by the other will be constant because they're equal with no phase delay

Comment: exactly, give or take noise :) but if you have measurable delay between the two microphones, our method should show some kind of peaks (by the way, the picture gets better when you use windowing functions to attenuate the leakage due to Gibb's phenomenon); and the variance (read: the inaccuracy) of this delay estimate should shrink the longer your observations get!